# Plotting surface within a box in Maple

Tags: maple

I'm given a surface $$S=x^2y^2+x^2z^2+y^2z^2=9$$ and I am being asked to plot the part of this surface which lies within a box with the dimensions $$[-10,10] \times [-10,10] \times [-10,10]$$

I understand how to plot the surface, but I'm not sure how to plot within this box. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `plots:-implicitplot3d(x^2*y^2+x^2*z^2+y^2*z^2=9, x=-10..10,y=-10..10,z=-10..10,grid=[100,100,100],style=patchnogrid);`

[image]